# Calling function with parenthesis doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I run my code, which is supposed to print the senders name, "adopted", and then the first mentioned user

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js', 'async', 'discord-message-handler');
const bot = new Client();
const cfg = require('./config.json');
function adoptaUser() {
    var finalString = '';

    finalString += '**' + (user.username) + 'adopted' + (message.mentions.member.first) + '**' + ':heart:';
}

//Skips to command here!!

if(message.content.includes('hws:adopt')) {
    message.channel.send(adoptaUser(message.author.id));
}
    });

});

bot.login(cfg.token);
    //I only included the code which the function uses!!
```

While no syntax errors are visible, I still get this error:

```
Bot Ready on 2 servers
C:\Users\REMOVED\Desktop\Bot2\app.js:16
finalString += '**' + (user.username) + 'has adopted' + (message.mentions.member.first) + '**' + ':heart:';
                       ^

ReferenceError: user is not defined
at adoptaUser (C:\Users\Moneq\Desktop\AutoRole\app.js:16:28)
at Client.bot.on.message (C:\Users\Moneq\Desktop\AutoRole\app.js:38:30)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Moneq\Desktop\AutoRole\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Moneq\Desktop\AutoRole\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Moneq\Desktop\AutoRole\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Moneq\Desktop\AutoRole\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Moneq\Desktop\AutoRole\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Though when I try to call the function without parenthesis, I get a response from the bot though it sends the actual function and not the string.

Any help on this?

Comment: Where are `user` and `message` declared/defined?

Comment: It's as @Pointy say's you need to define `user` and `message`

Comment: Unrelated, but you cannot "try to call a function without parenthesis", because you're no longer calling it by definition (the exception being getters/setters).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the user.id to the adoptaUser function when it appears that function is expecting a message object.

change to this:

```
message.channel.send(adoptaUser(message));
```

Then change this:

```
(user.username)
```

to this

```
message.author.username
```

You also need to add the return keyword to your adoptaUser function.

"calling" the function without the parenthesis is not a function call, it's a reference to the function object so it will indeed return the contents of the object.